# CoreMotion activity tracker in background

Tags: ios, background, core-motion, apple-m7

Is it possible to use the CoreMotion M7 capabilities to track the user activity in background and based on the received events to start/stop services like : location, bluetooth?

I know that the inverse operation is possible. For example, using location tracking in background can allow me to use the CoreMotion API to call its handlers in background.

What I want instead is to optimise the battery consumption by starting certain events base on the tracked activity from the background.